# Search field - laravel

Tags: forms, search, laravel, laravel-4

My search in laravel doesn't work. I'm trying everything, but I've got error: Class 'Bike' not found.

Index.blade:

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'/'))}}
{{Form::text('keyword', null, array('placeholder'=>'Miasto'))}}
{{Form::submit('search')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

route:

```
Route::post('/',function(){

$keyword = Input::get('keyword');

$bikes = Bike::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();

var_dump('search results');

foreach($bikes as $bike){

    var_dump($bike->city);

}
```

Comment: Have you updated Composer's autoload files?  From your project's root, run `php composer.phar dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload` (depending on your configuration).

Comment: Does a Bike extends Eloquent ?

Comment: I have updated composer. Bike extends eloquent.

Comment: Can we see your Bike model?

Comment: where does is the file stored for the Bike class?

Comment: @SamSullivan as of Laravel 4.1, the correct syntax would be "php artisan dump-autoload"

Comment: @TonyArra they didn't specify the version and you should always be able to use Composer directly.

Comment: @SamSullivan, the question is tagged as laravel-4.

Answer (score -1):

You are not returning anything.

```
return var_dump($bike->city);
```

Comment: Lools like we need more info then... someone above asked you to post your Bike model class.